# How do I install JavaTM Advanced Imaging API v1.1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, software-installation, image-processing

I'm trying compare images as described on [this Website](http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp) but therefor I need to have JAI installed. I have downloaded the file jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64.tar.gz from [here](http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/).

I've also looked into the [installationguide](http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html) but I feel kind of lost and don't know how to go on from here.

My specs:

OS:
Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr - 64bit

Java:
java version "1.6.0_41"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

If any other information is needed, I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the version in the official repositories if you can. Just run this to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libjai-core-java
```

If you still want to go your way, just download a binary version, add executable permissions and run it:

```
wget http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jre.bin
chmod +x jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jre.bin
sudo ./jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jre.bin

# finally, you can delete the installer if you want
rm jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64-jre.bin
```

Comment: I installed it from the official repo but for some reason eclipse still says ***The import javax.media cannot be resolved***

Comment: I now this turn out to be a problem that might better be asked on stackoverflow, but since I started this question here, I might as well continue here, so:
I've now downloaded the JMF as described [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/613587/vc/install-Java-Media-Framework-eclipse) and added it in eclipse as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163524/eclipse-missing-imports-javax-media-and-com-sun-media)
Now eclipse says: ***The import javax.media.jai. cannot be resolved***

Comment: I finally solved my problem. I just extracted the file jai-1_1_3-lib-linux-amd64.tar.gz into /opt/JAI and added it to my project via
***right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Libraries -> Add External JARs -> select /opt/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/jai_codec.jar and /opt/JAI/jai-1_1_3/lib/jai_core.jar

Comment: @Jamie-505 did the libjai-core-java package out of apt not work for you? I've tried using it for my application but even if I copy their jars on top of the pure-java jai jars my application shipped with, it doesn't run. :\

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package libjai-core-java` under `16.04`. Any hint for that?